# How to store image of Ubuntu on existing machine and then use it to install on a fleet of machines over local network

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, pxe, disk-image

I haven't found a clear answer or way of doing what I'm looking for. I'm used to doing this on a Windows environment, and was simply wondering if I could do the same with Ubuntu.

I'd like to start with a fresh installation on a laptop with Ubuntu, then add and remove software I deem necessary for the fleet of laptops I wish to configure. Ideally, I would take a "snapshot" of the laptop I've configured, store it on a server and whatever computer I connect to the local network (via ethernet) will be able to network boot (PXE?) into an installation guide and install the configuration I've specified.

Is there a way?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You can make a disk image of your installation using Disks, (booted from a second drive) and overwrite other drives using Disks in Ubuntu or Windows Disk Imager in Windows. Disks comes with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) offers two different modalities to do that; a [Lite Server](https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/11_lite_server) which sounds like it would do what you want, or the more complex [Server Edition](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-SE/#clonezilla-se).

Comment: That does it! Thanks